Can I log structured Splunk event from Quarkus using Splunk HEC and Slf4j?
I am quite new with Java, a bit newer with Quarkus and totally new to Splunk.
I am working on a Quarkus microservice using (quite magically) Sl4j to send application logs to Splunk.
using
@Slf4j
...
log.info(...)
This is working very well but in Splunk I don't get exactly what I want.
I would like to have my json event such as:
{"provider":"XX","price":"12.02"} 
on which I would like to do searches, compute KPIs, etc...
but I am getting something like
{"severity":"INFO","message":"... {\"provider\":\"XX\", \"price\":\"12.02\"} ...}
which seems to be standard.
My question is: do I have a way to get rid off this wrapping?
I am trying to look at a lot of different documentations and feel totally lost.
Is it something I have to change in my code? Something I have to define in Splunk?
Am I trying something that cannot work?
If anyone could give a clue I would appreciate a lot!
Thanks a lot!
PS I have tried to change the format, use flat/nested format, tried in various menus of Splunk (Data input, index definition etc...), but I have no clue on how to progress.
